# How to split an array in to two array Based on objectAtIndex in iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, json

i am newbie in iOS development i want to split an JSON parsing array in to two array Base on objectAtIndex how it possible? i want to make two array firstArray and SecondArray from my JSON parsing array here i want first array Contain only FirstObject of my JSON parsing array and SecondArray contain all remaining JSON array Value. i write for FirstArray like as.

```
self.firstArray=[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Here imageArray is my JSON parsing array. it is working but now i want to add all remanning Value of my imageArray in to second array How it is possible? if it is possible then please give me Solution.

Comment: copy that array and remove first object from copied array.

Comment: How to Copy it and remove it please give me any resource for that.

Comment: r u got the solution ?

Comment: Sorry For let Reply But i got a solution thnx all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if secondArray is NSMutableArray

```
self.secondArray=[self.imageArray mutableCopy];
[self.secondArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

or this if it is NSArray

```
 self.secondArray=[self.imageArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, self.imageArray.count-1)];
```

BTW Is your first object of the JSON of type array ? if it's an array then you are good to go. If not then you will need to add it to the `firstArray`
You can use this if `firstArray` is NSMutableArray

```
  [self.firstArray addObject:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

or this if it is NSArray

```
 self.firstArray=[self.imageArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Copy array:
NSArray *newABC = [NSArray arrayWithArray:someOtherArray];
Remove First Object
[self.newABC removeObjectAtIndex:0]
```